# ¿Como ajustar una aplicación hecha con tkinter a cualquier tamaño de pantalla?

Tags: python, tkinter

estoy relaizando una aplicación con python y su módulo tkinter. Todos los widgets los estoy colocando mediante grid, en la mayoría no se especifican el ancho o largo salvo en algunas etiquetas o marcos.
Al ejecutar dicho programa en otra pantalla, este no se ajusta a ella. Para que aparezca en toda la pantalla realizo el siguiente proceso:

```
    an = self.root.winfo_screenwidth()
    al = self.root.winfo_screenheight()
    tam = '%dx%d'%(an,al)
    self.root.geometry(tam)
```

Pero no ocupa todo el tamaño al cambiar de pantalla y al hacer la ventana más o menos grande los widgets no se adaptan al tamaño, me gustaría saber como solucionarlo.
Gracias

Comment: La ventana se crea con el tamaño que le indiques ,pero si después de hacerlo cambias el tamaño de ventana, has de usar 'root.update()' para que se redibuje de nuevo según el nuevo tamaño. Tienes que colocar esta instrucción después del evento que provoca el cambio de pantalla.

Comment: Respecto al tamaño de los widgets, este no cambiará con la ventana, a no ser que indiques que queden fijados a los lados que desees, pero el comportamiento de esto puede no ser el esperado si hay muchos widgets por recolocar. Debes usar para cada widget la opción 'sticky' de este modo:  self.grid(sticky="nsew"), donde 'nswe' significa 'norte', sur', 'este', y 'oeste' respectívamente. Puedes usar cualquier combinación de estos valores.

Comment: En lo personal, para no tener que lidiar con este tipo de problemas, directamente hago que el tamaño de la ventana no pueda ser cambiado por el usuario.

Comment: También hago que el tamaño sea constante sin importar el tamaño de la pantalla. No es una solución, pero es una buena alternativa.

Comment: A mí también me parece lo mejor, en general.

Comment: El problema es que la aplicación se va a ejecutar con un escritorio remoto con un dispositivo del que no se el tamaño de su pantalla (puede ser unordenador portatil o una tablet), ¿Se os ocurre algo?